# Can 2021 be hypotenuse of a pythagorean triangle?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

I'm looking for Pythagorean triangles with a hypotenuse of length 2021. In other words, let $z=2021$ then, $z^2=x^2+y^2$ for some integers $x$, $y$. Now, when I put a hypotenuse value of 2021 to generate Pythagorean triples using an [online calculator](https://www.had2know.org/academics/pythagorean-triple-calculator-hypotenuse.html), it shows that there are no solutions i.e. no such pythagorean triangle exists.

However, $z^2=2021^2=43^2 \cdot 47^2$ and $43, 47$ are both of the form $4k+3$, so by sum of two squares theorem, since the two exponents are even, $z^2=x^2+y^2$ should be solvable...

I think there might be a flaw in my logic somewhere. Could someone clarify on this and also provide a proof in case such a triangle cannot exist?

Comment: This theorem deals with numbers that are the sum of AT MOST two squares. A single square is allowed as well. Note also that not the fact that both prime factors are of the form $4k+3$ is relevant , but , as you pointed out later , that every exponent correspoding with a prime factor of the form $4k+3$ is even is the relevant fact.

Comment: The sum of two squares theorem says precisely the opposite: "An integer greater than one can be written as a sum of two squares if and only if its prime decomposition contains no factor $p^k$, where prime $p\equiv 3{\pmod {4}}$ and $k$ is odd." Note that $43 = 4 \cdot 10 + 3$ and and $1$ is odd, so 2021 cannot be expressed as the sum of two squares.

Comment: The sum of two squares theorem allows zero. Indeed, the only solution to $x^2+y^2=9$ is $(0,3)$ or $(3,0).$ You are misreading the theorem if you think it doesn't allow $0.$

Comment: @PhysMath This is only a reformulation of what I said. And again : the two square theorem does allow zero-squares. It would , as shown , otherwise be false.

Comment: The "Core Points" of the confusion are **(1)** Can $2021^2=4084441$ (not $2021$) be the sum of 2 Squares ? YES , though $0$ must be included ! **(2)** Can $2021$ be the sum of 2 squares ? NO ! **(3)** Can "A Pythagorean triangle" have hypotenuse $2021$ ? NO ! **(4)** Can "A Pythagorean triangle" have hypotenuse $2021^2=4084441$ ? NO !

Comment: @PhysMath by the statement you've provided, I believe that means when we do have factor $p^k$ with even $k$ (in other words, no $p^k$ with odd $k$) in the prime decomposition, the integer can be written as a sum of squares...?

Comment: The simplest way to solve it is to look 2021 up in https://oeis.org/A008846 which does not include 2021.

Comment: @R.J.Mathar Trusting blindly in OEIS-sequences might be dangerous (in this case probably not), the sequences are not checked by someone else.

Comment: The closest two hypotenuses are $2025$ and $2017$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following two articles:

[Generating a Triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) and
[Sum of Two Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem).

Since $~43 \equiv 3 \pmod{4},~$ and $~43 ~| ~2021$, the two articles collectively imply that $2021$ can not be the *hypotenuse* of a **primitive** pythagorean triple.

That is, if it is a primitive, then you would have to have

$$m^2 + n^2 = 2021$$

which is impossible.

This leaves the issue of whether it can be a **non-primitive** hypotenuse of a pythagorean triple.

However, since $~43 \times 47 = 2021,~$ this possibility can be **manually eliminated** by examining the elements in $\{1,4,9,16,25,36\}$.

That is, it is impossible to take any two of those elements and have them sum to either $43$ or $47$.

Therefore, it is **game over**.

---

**Edit** 
Upon reflection, both $43$ and $47$ are congruent to $3 \pmod{4},$ so, manual examination of $\{1,4,9,16,25,36\}$ isn't necessary.

Comment: could you elaborate what exactly implies that 2021 cannot be primitive hypotenuse? Am I misunderstanding the theorem?

Comment: @Meow By the 1st linked article, if $2021$ is a primitive hypotenuse, then it is expressible as $m^2 + n^2.$  By the 2nd linked article, since the prime factorization of $2021$ is $43 \times 47$ and $43 \equiv 3\pmod{4}$, that is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

In the sum of two squares theorem, one of the two squares is allowed to be zero. And indeed, $2021^2=2021^2+0^2$.

---

My answer was apparently too short to be clear, so let me expand. OP is confused because there appear to be contradicting facts:

- 2021 is not the hypotenuse of a right triangle.
- The "sum of squares theorem" says that an integer can be written as the sum of two squares iff its prime decomposition does not contain primes $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ with an odd exponent.
- $2021^2 = 43^2 \times 47^2$ is an integer whose prime decomposition does not contain any prime $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ with odd exponent: all the exponents are even.

So, where's the contradiction? The answer is what I've written above:

> In the sum of two squares theorem, one of the two squares is allowed to be zero. And indeed, $2021^2=2021^2+0^2$.

If I need to state this in an even clearer way: the "sum of two squares theorem" cannot be used to determine if an integer $a$ is part of a Pythagorean triple. The reason is simple, $a^2$ will *never* contain a prime $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ with an odd exponent! The sum of two squares theorem always applies, and says that $a^2$ can be written as a sum of two (possibly zero!) squares. But that much is obvious: $a^2 = a^2 + 0^2$.

Comment: No, it is not allowed. They must be natural numbers

Comment: Yes, it is allowed ("it" meaning "zero in the two squares theorem"). This answer explains exactly what OP's confusion is. I don't understand the downvotes. Every square is trivially a solution of the two squares theorem, yet not every square fits in a Pythagorean triple so you cannot use the former to solve the latter.

Comment: Thanks for explaining :) It was helpful to clear up a misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because the integer $n$ is a sum of two squares only when its prime factors which are congruent with $3$ modulo $4$ have an exponent even in the representation $n=\prod p_i^{n_i}$. If $2021^2=x^2+y^2$ then we must have $(2021,x,y)=(a^2+b^2,2ab,a^2-b^2)$ as it is well known.

Then, because $2021=43\cdot47$ we cannot have $2021$ as hypotenuse of a right triangle.

Comment: Neither $43$ nor $47$ is a sum of two squares so no question of primitive or non-primitive.

Comment: Right.  That was the missing part.

Comment: And why you have deleted your first "objection"? The only possibility to be a non-primitive hypotenuse is that at least one factor of $n$  be  a sum of two squares.

Comment: I deleted my first objection because you left an explanatory comment that showed that $2021$ (also) couldn't be a non-primitive hypotenuse.

Answer (score -2):

To form a pythagorean triangle they must be natural numbers, so you can't use the **sum of two squares theorem** to find them. Instead you can use **Euclid's formula** to find:
a=2021,b=180,c=2029

Of course, a is not the hypotenuse in this case